# Case statement in Oracle showing everything instead of queried items

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I'm working on a movies database for class, and I have to create a query where it will get the title and the date the movie was released, and show those columns when, and only when, the movie title contains the city designated or there is an actor/actress related to the movie who was born or died in that city. The problem comes when I have to add a third column saying some information about what realtion the movie has to the city given (title contains it, actor is related to city, etc). I was given previous help, telling me to use a CASE statement (I'm using Oracle) and this is what I came down to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.titulo, o.fecha_estreno,
CASE 
    WHEN UPPER(o.titulo) LIKE '%ZARAGOZA%' AND EXISTS(SELECT p.id_obra FROM Pelicula p WHERE p.id_obra = o.id_obra) THEN 'Titulo'
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT pa.id_obra 
        FROM Participa pa
            WHERE pa.id_obra = id_obra AND EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT l.nombre FROM Lugar l
                WHERE UPPER(l.nombre) LIKE '%ZARAGOZA%' AND EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT tl.id_lugar FROM TieneLugar tl
                    WHERE tl.id_lugar = l.id_lugar AND tl.id_profesional = pa.id_profesional))) THEN 'Actor relacionado con lugar'
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT er.id_obra 
        FROM EstaRelacionado er 
            WHERE er.id_obra = id_obra AND EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT k.keyword 
            FROM Keywords k
                WHERE k.id_keyword = er.id_keyword AND UPPER(k.keyword) LIKE '%ZARAGOZA%')) THEN 'Keyword relacionada con pelicula'
    END AS Causa
FROM Obra o;
```

But that will just show all the movie titles, even if they're not related at all. I've found out that it just won't go into any WHEN statement, and it will just SELECT DISTINCT all titles. Is there some way to fix this and show the result as it should? Example:

```
  TITULO          FECHA_ESTRENO              CAUSE
----------       ----------------    ---------------------
Barcelona mia         1967             Title contains city
Lights out            1985             Actor is related to place
```

**EDIT:** E.g. In lights out, there's an actor who has an event assigned to it (was born, or died) which contains the city searched for.

This query should just show 300 elements. It's showing 4400. I know it has to do with the WHERE clause, but I tried writing WHERE Cause IS NOT NULL; and that wouldn't work as the column Cause doesn't really exist

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: "But that will just show all the movie titles", which no wonder, you have no `WHERE` clause in the outer query.

Comment: @stickybit - please consider making that an answer so it can be upvoted.

Comment: @BobJarvis: Done.

Comment: I edited the question to show one more expected result, and my knowledge about the WHERE clause. I just don't know what to write in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query shows all movies, because you have no `WHERE` clause in your outer query.

The [`WHERE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) clause is the part of the query that tells the database which properties the returned rows should have. (Actually `WHERE`is one of them, others can have that effect too, but that shall not matter here and now, you don't currently use one of these either). If you omit the `WHERE` clause, all rows of the table(s) are returned.

Comment: Thank you! But what should I write in the WHERE? I just wanted them to show if the REASON column is empty.

Comment: @EnriqueTorres: Well, you have three conditions in you handle in your case. I assume you want to have all movies where any of these conditions are true? So the simplest thing you could do is try and use these in the `WHERE` along with the `OR` operator.